# Anaconda not able to import the packages like numpy, scipy, theano etc

Tags: python, anaconda

Without installing Anaconda, everything works fine.
That is, I am able to import the above mentioned packages. But after installing Anaconda, I am not able to import the same packages. Here is the error which I get: -

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line  199, in <module>
from . import random
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py",   line 99, in <module>
from .mtrand import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random /mtrand.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

Comment: Best is to make virtual envs containing what you need for different projects. Eg `conda create -n myenv anaconda` then `source activate myenv`. Everything should work fine inside the virtual environment. Something to try, anyway.

Comment: without conda, everything is getting imported like scipy,numpy etc. Don't know why is it happening here.Maybe due to some path problem.

Comment: Did you accept the option to append to your path when you installed? It's not the default.

Comment: Is it possible you are running the 'stock' python that comes on the machine?  I ask this because the path points to /usr/local/lib/python2.7, which feels like "stock" python to me.  Usually, we install Anaconda elsewhere on the machine /usr/bin/anaconda or something, so make sure you are running the Python that works anaconda, not the "stock" Python?

Comment: I had appended the path. Don't know why is it still using the stock python.

Answer (score 1):

Once you install the Anaconda distribution it appends the .bashrc paths with the location of the anaconda/bin.
This means that any python packages installed in the /usr/local/ may not be importable.

I second the suggestion above and recommend using virtual environments to do your work. The Anaconda Python distribution comes with conda package management. This may make your life easier.

You can create a new environments and install packages not provided by the distribution using conda build(http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials.html)

Also look at pip and python wheel.

Comment: I had done to create a virtual environment using the command

    'conda create -n myenv numpy'. 
However I get this error. 
    'Error:     Could not open u'/home/sahil/anaconda2/pkgs/wheel- 0.29.0- py27_0.tar.bz2.part' for writing (seek).'